# Custom View. attrs array

Tags: android, android-xml

I have a custom view with 4 rectangles in it. I want to make this view configurable from xml.

Is it possible to make it like:

```
custom:rectColor="red|cyan|blue|green" //each color correspond rectangle
```

with

```
    <attr name="rectColor" format="color">
        <flag name="red" value="2" />
        <flag name="cyan" value="5" />
        <flag name="blue" value="7" />
        <flag name="green" value="9" />
    </attr>
```

Or it must be:

```
    <attr name="firstRectColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="secondRectColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="thirdRectColor" format="color" />
    <attr name="fourthRectColor" format="color" />
```

and each view should contains:

```
    custom:firstRectColor="red"
    custom:secondRectColor="red"
    custom:thirdRectColor="red"
    custom:fourthRectColor="red"
```

And if it possible. How can I get set of color values from attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

Read this documentation.. it shows you how to declare custom attributes and access them in your layout file..

http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html